# Javascript request for JSON result in ASP.NET MVC 3 using Forms Authentication

Tags: javascript, json, rest, asp.net-mvc-3, restful-authentication

I have an MVC 3 REST API that has a simple controller: `ApiController`. There is a method `Foo` in `ApiController` that takes some string information in and returns a JSON result:

```
public class ApiController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Foo(string input)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to have a JQuery method call Foo with some user-entered data and display the result.

The catch here is that I want to check that the user is allowed access to Foo. What's the best way to go about this in ASP.NET MVC 3? I think the answer is to use SSL and basic authentication, but I have no idea what that would look like. Also, do I have to roll my own password hashing/salting or is there some way to just use Forms Authentication?

**Edit**: Note that I'm trying to create an API that third-party developers can use. For example, if someone writes a Rapportive-style browser plug-in that scans your Gmail, sends the text to Foo, and displays it in the browser.

Also, I believe just using Forms Authentication will send the username/password information in plain text, right? I'm not sure how to implement SSL to prevent this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use FormsAuthentication and the `[Authorize]` attribute. So you might have a `AccountController` with a LogOn action which will be accessible only through HTTPS. This controller will allow clients to authenticate and get an authentication cookie which will be reused for accessing the API:

```
public class AccountController: Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [RequireHttps]
    public ActionResult LogOn(string username, string password)
    {
        // TODO: verify the credentials and emit an authentication cookie if valid
        // return some result (JSON?) to indicate whether the operation succeeded or
        // not
    }
}
```

then all that's left is to decorate your other controller actions that you want to secure with the `[Authorize]` attribute:

```
public class ApiController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public JsonResult Foo(string input)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

So now a client will need to first call the LogOn action and fetch the corresponding authentication cookie in the response which will be sent along subsequent calls to your API.

Comment: Thanks Darin, I didn't know about RequireHttps. I still have the question of how do I allow 3rd-party developers to build using my API. I want a stateless API where they basically submit username/pw every time they make a call. For instance, if some rails developer wants to build a web app that calls Foo, it shouldn't be a problem, they just call the URL with the appropriate username/pw for their developer account. Similar to how Facebook uses developer keys I suppose.

Comment: @Wesley Tansey, in this case you could write a custom `Authorize` attribute in which you would verify the validity of some token passed by the client. It could be a custom HTTP header or something else. Could be username/password or you could send clients some private key which will be required for them to send along each request and which you would decrypt in the overriden `AuthorizeCore` method and verify its validity.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was thinking. Seems like such a common task should be more straight-forward in .NET. Doesn't almost everybody building a web app need a developer API these days?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [Authorize] attribute to do what you want here.  See the following details and example on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx

You can authorize specific users, or users within a specific Role.

The default Forms-based authentication provided when you create a new (non-empty) ASP.NET MVC project will enable you to authorize users.

Comment: I'm aware of the Authorize attribute. I don't know if that will work for me though. I want to create a developer API that third-party applications can use, preferably a stateless API. For example, imagine a Rapportive-style browser plug-in that reads your emails in Gmail and processes them with Foo, then displays the result in the browser.